# QUAL 2K modelling software

Tags: software-installation, software-center, software-sources

I am trying to install a water quality modeling software called QUAL 2K via WINE but i am unable to install as my wine is showing error only for this software is there any other way  to install this software or is there QUAL 2K available for UBUNTU

Answer (score 0):

Install Wine, then download and unpack your software:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
wget http://www.qual2k.com/download/Q2Kv2_12b1.zip
unzip Q2Kv2_12b1.zip
```

Try to launch it:

```
WINEARCH=win32 wine q2kfortran2_12.exe

wine: created the configuration directory '/home/xenial/.wine'
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0x10ee8a0, overlapped 0x10ee8ac): stub
wine: configuration in '/home/xenial/.wine' has been updated.

               ╔═══════════════════════════════════════════════╗
               ║                                               ║
               ║                    QUAL2K                     ║
               ║                                               ║
               ║           Ver 2.11b8 - Mar 2009               ║
               ║                                               ║
               ╟───────────────────────────────────────────────╢
               ║                                               ║
               ║           User should register with:          ║
               ║                                               ║
               ║                 Steven C. Chapra              ║
               ║             Hua Tao, Greg Pelletier           ║
               ║                                               ║
               ║             steven.chapra@tufts.edu           ║
               ║                                               ║
               ║     Department of Civil and Environmental     ║
               ║                  Engineering                  ║
               ║                Tufts University               ║
               ║                Medford, MA 02155              ║
               ║                                               ║
               ╚═══════════════════════════════════════════════╝
1
```

Also it shows warning window:

[image: warning window]

I do not know is it expected result or not, but it seems to be working.